# Vector spaces - "over a field"

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I recently learned about vector spaces, and had two questions:

1. What do we mean by saying **“vector space over a field”**? I read many posts and listened to lectures but it seems to me that people have different definitions/explanations for the terminology **“over a field”** – in one lecture, the professor said that when we say a vector space "over a field" we mean that the scalars with which we multiply the elements of the vector space are taken from some field **F**. In another lecture, a professor said that “over a field” means that the components of the elements in the vector space are from some field **F**.
   After hearing their explanations, I got confused – does the terminology “over a field” refers to the elements of the vector space themselves or to the scalars we multiply the vectors in the V.S. with?

I would appreciate it if you could explain the terminology of “over a field” in more detail than those professors did.

2. When talking about a polynomial over a field **F**, we mean that the coefficients of the polynomial are taken from some field **F**. My question is the following: do the roots of the polynomial are from the field F because the coefficients belong there too, or in other words – does the choice of a field of the coefficients determines the field to which the roots of the polynomial belong?

Sorry about the bad English (I'm not a native speaker) and the silly question, I just started learning linear algebra so it’s still new and hard for me…

Thank you very much for reading my question!

Comment: 1. Field: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics) . Note that e.g. $\mathbb Q, \mathbb R, \mathbb C$ are fields. For the start, it is a good idea to just pretend that your field is $\mathbb R$ and follow that intuition. 2. If coefficients belong to a field, the roots might belong to that field or to a "bigger" field. For example, the roots $\pm\sqrt{2}\not\in\mathbb Q$ even if the coefficients of $x^2-2$ belong to $\mathbb Q$. The roots $\pm i\not\in\mathbb R$ even if the coefficients of $x^2+1$ belong to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Every vector space is over a field. The field is usually $\Bbb R$ when you first encounter vector spaces. It turns out any finite dimensional vector space over $\Bbb F$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb F^n$ for some $n$. but in general, you should consider vectors and scalars to be different things.

Comment: More generally, we have modules over rings. This is defined in basically the same way, but where the ring $R$ of scalars can be something like the integers, $\Bbb Z$. In the special case where $R$ is a field, a module is just a vector space over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: And yes - it is the *scalars* (for scalar multiplication) come from a field. The vectors are abstract entities, they don't "have" components per se. To have components ("co-ordinates") - you first need to have a "co-ordinate system" (i.e. a *basis*), which is a *tuple* of linearly-independent vectors that span the whole space. Then, if the base is $(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)$, for a vector $v$ there is a unique representation of $v=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\ldots+a_nv_n$, where $a_i$ are the scalars (from the field), and *then* you can call those scalars the "components" of the vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This circles back to the definition of a vector space:
a vector space $V$ *over a field $F$* is a set with two operations $+ : V \times V \to V$ and $\cdot : F \times V \to V$ such that

1. $(V,+)$ is an abelian group
2. $+, \cdot$ are compatible with the field operations: $1 \cdot v = v$, $(ab) \cdot v = a \cdot (b \cdot v)$, $a \cdot (u + v) = a \cdot v + a \cdot v$, $(a + b) \cdot v = a \cdot v + b \cdot v$

So this "over some field" is baked right into the definition - it just means "the elements we can multiply our vectors by". For example if you take the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual operations you can multiply each element by real numbers and thus it's a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, but you could also multiply them by rational numbers which means it's also a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

1. When we say that $V$ is a vector space over a field $F$, what that means is your first option: that the scalars are taken from $F$. For instance $\Bbb R$ is a $1$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$, and an infinite-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Q$.
2. It needs context. If we say that $P(x)$ has no roots, it is a good idea to add *where* it has no roots. For instance $x^2+1\in\Bbb R[x]$ and it has no roots in $\Bbb R$, but it has roots in $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 0):

pretty late for me to reply but do correct me if I am wrong, the answer to your first question was answered by yourself since the field of a vector space is defined by the properties that you were confused about.

To clarify what I meant, to define a vector space we need some representation for the magnitude of every dimension. For that representation we take help of elements from a field (the components). And to stretch a vector we'd multiply it by an element from that field itself (scalars). A simple example for a field could be real numbers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).